# Does cPython use multiple cores for built-in functions such as sort, any, all?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpython, python-internals

I understand that cPython has a GIL so that your script can't run on multiple cores without using the multiprocessing module. But is there anything to stop the built in functions such as sorting using multiple cores? I don't understand cPython structure but I think the question I'm asking is 'are builtin functions like sort, any and list comprehensions actually below the GIL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cPython GIL has to do with only allowing a single thread to run bytecode within a process -- it's not related to the non-abstracted CPU.

That said, as of now, unless you're calling something to fork/use multiple processes or your OS/hardware is catching calls and doing this for you (highly unlikely), you will see all your operations happen on a single CPU core.

Built-in functions that are implemented in C happen "below the GIL" as they're more direct calls to underlying APIs, but putting arguments and data to those functions happens within the GIL, as you're using bytecode to read and write.

As an aside, if you want to better understand the cPython relationship to its host, I'd suggest the following [high-level official overview](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) and/or [the PDF slides and the playground that I wrote for a conference](https://github.com/tristanfisher/ffi4wd).

Comment: The GIL is not just about byte code. Reference counts must only be updated under the GIL too, which means stuff that manipulates references counts at all can't release the GIL when it's doing so. `any`, `all` and `sorted` are run entirely under the GIL, because lots of reference count manipulation is occurring in all of them, even if byte code is not necessarily being executed (e.g. in the case of `sorted` using builtin types where comparisons are at the C layer too). There have been tests of using atomic operations to maintain ref counts, and it always slowed CPython unacceptably.

Comment: I'm not sure that I stated that the GIL _only_ has to do with bytecode -- I was addressing the question's focus on the "front end" of Python - sort/any/list.  Passing arguments to those happens in byte code.

Comment: You didn't, but the main issue preventing any use of `sorted`/`any`/`all` from ever releasing the GIL (even if they could guarantee that the items being processed never executed byte code for comparisons, generating values, applying predicates, etc.). The OP's question was about ability to parallelize and GIL restrictions, not what is byte code and what isn't. The built-ins are below the byte code layer, but they are not free of the GIL, because even if the work they did could be guaranteed to never execute byte code (it can't), even code entirely in C using Python objects needs the GIL.

Comment: Hmm... It's possible I'm misinterpreting the phrase "below the GIL". When I hear "below" I interpret it as "the GIL is operating on high, in Python, and being 'below' would mean 'not affected by the GIL'". But the otherwise synonymous in non-jargon English word "under [the GIL]" would in threading jargon mean "with the GIL held". So when you say "Built-in functions that are implemented in C happen 'below the GIL'", I hear it as "the built-in C functions release the GIL allowing parallelism", and I'm not 100% sure that's what you meant...

Comment: I was using the phrase "below the GIL" because the asker had employed it, but I probably should have made it more clear that I didn't mean that the VM allows for other threads to do work when there's a blocking call that interfaces with C.

Answer (score 2):

None of the functions you mention parallelize automatically. In general, silently spawning threads is considered poor form in most languages (this is changing, but it's still only seen in pure functional languages where thread safety is baked in by design); spawning lots of threads without giving warning is how you get mysterious errors when the user tries to launch their own threads in and get transient errors due to having too many running threads. So even if the GIL wasn't an issue, it would not make sense to do this.

That said, the GIL is there to protect interpreter internals, and that covers any scenario where reference counts are manipulated, which is constantly; with rare exception, it's not possible to do any meaningful work on `PyObject*`s (which is what all Python level types are represented as in C) with the GIL held. Typically, Python built-ins only release the GIL for blocking operations (I/O, waiting on locks, etc.); it's only in third party C extensions (and `ctypes`) where GIL release is normal, because in those cases, they convert the `PyObject`s entirely to C level types, release the GIL now that no reference counting or other internals are being touched, do the expensive work, reacquire the GIL, and convert the results back from C level types to Python level objects.